# Forcing Genymotion to use my home wifi

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

By default Genymotion (virtualbox) uses a host wifi named "WiredSSID". How can I force it to use my home wifi?

I have tried changing the Adapter 1 and Adapter 2 of Virtualbox Network Settings to use Bridged Adapter > en0: Wifi (Airport)
but it resets back to the default on Adapter 1 and does nothing to change network wifi on Adapter 2.

I am using Genymotion 2.2.2, Virtualbox 4.3.12 r93733 on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Genymotion always use your Laptop's or Desktop's Internet.
It just showing you wifi symbol. It do not connect to your physical world dude...

It's virtual thing.

Comment: If that's true, Chromecast installed on android genymotion should ideally work and let me stream from youtube android app to my television but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I just had to restart the genymotion emulator couple of times. WiredSSID is indeed the home wifi. It just didn't recognize in the beginning.

Comment: Sometimes emulator shows WiredSSID but there is no internet access. It is because Your android clock time is not the same as in your computer. I made java app to set time with you genymotion emulator. http://blog.mokrzycki.io/2015/06/change-time-in-genymotion-emulator-simple-java-app/ or you can use adb command instead.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me. Go to android setting, set date time and time zone. Then restart the emulator. It should work.

Comment: it has not worked for me unfortunately. Device time == computer time. Still no internet on device.